# Windows 2008 AD - Lost trust with Exchange Server (and others)

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange-2010

I have quite a serious issue where my first DC (DC1) has lost it's trust with our Exchange server (and other workstations and servers).

Independantly, DC2 has "trust" with the servers, but i've just found out hasn't been replicating.

DC2 alone will allow login, but exchange service will not start (presumably as the Operations Master is DC1).

I cannot move the roles using AD&C.

My main question (unless anyone has got some advice regarding the bigger problem) is - is it possible to re-add / reset comp account for a MS EXchange server in the domain?

"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed." is the error the user gets when logging on.

Any suggestions / ideas welcome?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to first get your replication to work again with your DC's? Maybe the problem fixes itself when AD is "Healthy" again?

Comment: `"presumably as the Operations Master is DC1"` There is no role called operations master. Did you mean that DC1 holds all 5 operations master roles? Also, this is **very** poorly worded. Take a deep breath, hit the edit button, and give a complete description of your AD and Exchange topologies. Also, where does this error show up? The Exchange server? What user is logging in to the Exchange server directly?

Comment: Also, your replication issues could be caused by bad DNS settings on the servers if everything else looks OK. You sound like you may be a little weak in how AD works and what it does. Maybe take a read [here](http://serverfault.com/q/402580/10472).

Answer (score 2):

Is time in sync between the servers?
Too big a time difference might be a cause for losing trust.