# Primary Domain Server Crashed. Restoring issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I have two servers. One is primary DC, another is ADC. Now the primary DC got crashed. ADC is serving the purpose now.
I need to format the Primary DC server to make it up. After installing the OS, how i need to bring it in domain as Primary DC??
Shall I add as ADC to the running one?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "primary" domain controller any more. There are just "domain controllers", one of which can hold the PDC role for legacy applications...

Comment: I am using Windows server 2003 R2. So shall I add the new one as ADC??

Comment: What do you mean by "ADC"? I've never seen that term before. You have "domain controllers", and have had for about 13 years. If a domain controller fails, you can either restore it from a Microsoft-sanctioned backup routine (that's critical for a domain controller), or you build a new, fresh machine and promote it to being a DC. If the *only* thing your domain controller was doing was being a DC (i.e. it wasn't running DHCP or WSUS or anything except AD and DNS) then just build a fresh machine, and promote it to a Domain Controller. Job done.

Comment: No offense but it sounds like you are way over your head here. I suggest you request an emergency budget to hire someone with the expertise to get your environment fixed now. A crisis is a bad time to learn.

Comment: ADC = Additional Domain Controller???

Comment: There is no such thing as an ADC, regardless of what the OP thinks it may stand for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seize the PDC Emulator role (and any other relevant roles) from the dead domain controller - [instructions on this process are here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787105(v=ws.10).aspx).

Once that's done, you'll probably also want to clean up the dead domain controller's metadata from the domain before trying to re-promote the server again with the fresh OS.  [Here's the documentation for that process](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498).

Comment: In a 2008 R2 DFL (which is sounds like the OP might have) the metadata cleanup process is as easy as deleting the dead DC computer object from AD.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the OP's comment. I can't read, apparently :)

Comment: @MDMarra With sufficiently bad font kerning, 3 == 8. ;)

Answer (score 5):

**There are no such thing as an ADC or PDC. They are all multimaster peers. Please [read this.](https://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-and-how-does-it-work)**

If the DC that crashed held any operations master roles, [then you need to transfer them to the other DC.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781578(v=ws.10).aspx) Clean up the metadata for the dead DC by [following these steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498). Then, reinstall the crashed server and promote it using `dcpromo` and you're done.