# How does a replicated DC handles w32tm changes?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, replication, ntp, w32time

We have 2 replicated W2K8R2 DC's.

I had updated one (DC1) with w32tm to get manual updates from asia NTP.  Everything syncs correctly.

My question: (In order to learn): How does this propagates to the replica (e.g. DC2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: [What is Active Directory and how does it work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-and-how-does-it-work)

> The PDC Emulator is also the server that controls time sync across the
>   domain. All other DCs sync their time from the PDC Emulator. All
>   clients sync their time from the DC that they logged in to. It's
>   important that everything remain within 5 minutes of each other,
>   otherwise Kerberos breaks and when that happens, everyone cries.

So when you change the time on your DC which holds the PDC Emulator Role, it will sync it to your other DC's.