# Linux DNS + Windows AD

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I got Linux DNS server running years ago, and we're trying to add an Active Directory server on the network.

The AD is congigured to have static IP, and a DNS A record pointed to it.

```
xxx.xx.27.15/adserver.xxxx....
```

Now, as I try to join a client to it, it fails. If I use the domain name, xxxx...., it will fail completly, as it says it can't find the controller to it. If I use the NetBIOS name, I get a prompt to input my account information, but then failed.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AD does not get a static IP address. Do you mean that your (presumably singular) domain controller has a static IP? It's not enough to create an A record for this, as AD requires many SRV (and other) records to function properly. While it is possible to manually create all of the needed entries, it is not a tenable solution in the long-term.

In lieu of creating manual static DNS entries, you want to create a subdomain (say ad.example.com) for your AD, and delegate control over that to your Windows DNS servers. This will permit AD to manage its own DNS namespace, creating and modifying the records it needs without you needing to muck about with manually changing things all the time.

For more information on AD and DNS (and many other crucial AD-related topics), please see [MDMarra's](https://serverfault.com/users/10472/mdmarra) spectacular Active Directory Q&A:

- [What is Active Directory and How Does it Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I got it, I think I am best off to create a subdomain for it.