# My dns name does not exist. When trying to add pc's to domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I have a server which is running dns,terminal,ad,etc and I am trying to get desktop computer to join the domain.

My server names is server.home.aplus.com (dont ask me why its so long)
The domain is home.aplus.com.

My server ip is 192.169.52.183 and when trying to get a pc on the domain I get the following message:

> : This information is intended for a network administrator.  If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\WINDOWS\debug\dcdiag.txt.
>
> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain home.aplus.com:
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
>   (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.home.aplus.com
>
> Common causes of this error include the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV record is not registered in DNS.
> - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:
>
> home.aplus.com
>   aplus.com
>   com
>   . (the root zone)
>
> For information about correcting this problem, click Help.

what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to take a guess based on the information provided, I'd guess that the PC isn't using the domain controller for DNS. If you only have one DC, make sure the the only thing in your client computers' DNS server list is `192.169.52.183`.

And it should go without saying that if you do only have one domain controller, you should work on getting a second ASAP, make it run DNS as well, and add it as a secondary DNS server to your clients.

Comment: why a second? Oh so your saying the computer im trying to make join the domain is poin to maybe my firewall or ISP DNS?

Comment: You should always have at least two Domain Controllers for any domain. You might want to [read through the AD Basics Q&A that I wrote here](http://serverfault.com/q/402580/10472). It covers a lot of stuff about AD that might be worth reading.

Comment: And to answer your second question, you should really only point your clients that are AD joined to use DNS services provided by your domain controllers unless you really know what you're doing. Just do an `ipconfig /all` and see if your domain controller is listed as the DNS server for the client. If it isn't, you need to change your configuration.