# Why is it desirable to have multiple domain controllers in the root domain?

Tags: active-directory

Why is it desirable to have multiple domain controllers in the root domain in Windows Server with Active Directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Active Directory and how does it work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Empty root domains are a legacy recommendation. They rarely serve a purpose anymore. My advice is to have at least 2 DCs in *any* domain that you have, but to think long and hard before creating an empty root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that if one fails, you're not SOL.