# Domain Controller:: DHCP Scope is not showing up

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We just noticed that on our primary domain controller - the DHCP scope is missing.  We cannot see any of the IP addresses leased to any of the computers.  DHCP is working because the computers are being assigned the proper IP addresses - but Scope is not visible under DHCP.

Please help.

Comment: Unless you have Windows NT, you don't have a Primary Domain Controller. Those went away with Windows 2000 Server. Also, are you sure that this domain controller is actually also a DHCP server or is DHCP installed on another server?

Comment: then what should I refer the primary domain controller to then if I am running server 2008 r2 on both servers? we have a primary and secondary.

Comment: They are multi-master peers. There are no primary or secondary domain controllers after Windows NT4. They're just domain controllers.

Comment: thanks so much! so even though one server is primary, it still is called domain controller? or would it be referred to as multi-master peers?

Comment: Read up on FSMO roles; there is a PDCe role holder, but it's role is quite minor compare to what an NT 4.0 PDC had to handle.

Comment: `even though one server is primary, it still is called domain controller?` That's just the point. **One is not primary** they are both peers. There are FSMO roles for some special tasks, but that does not make one primary and one secondary. You might want to read this: http://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 5):

You probably have the DHCP console installed on your Domain Controller but are running the DHCP server on a different server. Run `ipconfig /all` from a DHCP client and see what it lists for a DHCP Server. I bet it won't be the DC.

Comment: it is the correct server.  I did netsh dhcp show server and it points to the server that I am having issues with. I did ipconfig /all on the other computers and it points to the same address of the troubled server.

Comment: Have you right clicked on the DHCP node in the console and clicked "Add Server" and added the server to the console view. If DHCP is working, then it's something in the console, not the server itself.

Comment: I did see that option - would that mess things up though? I don't want to take the whole network down.  I am just a little baffled on why DHCP is working and I cannot even see it listed under DHCP.

Comment: No, that will not "mess anything up." It simply adds a server to the view in the console. The console simply shows management options for managed servers. If you, or someone else using this user account, deleted the view from the console, then it makes perfect sense that the server is working fine but the console doesn't list the view for it. Add it back to the view and be done with it.