# Windows Server 2012 IPAM Provisioning: Server name should be given in FQDN format

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, ipam, windows

I have installed IPAM feature on my Windows Server 2012. When i run the following PowerShell Cmdlet to provision the IPAM GPOs:

```
Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning -Domain mydomainname -GpoPrefixName IPAM -Force
```

i get this error:

```
Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning : Server name mydomainname should be given in 'Fully Qualified Domain Name' format.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning -Domain mydomainname -GpoPrefixName IPAM -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidArgument,Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning
```

According to my AD DNS settings, *mydomainname* it is indeed the FQDN format of the domain name. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have what is called a "single-label" domain name. This is bad. Single label domain names were never recommended, though you were allowed to "hang yourself," so to speak, and create one anyway prior to 2008 R2.

This incompatibility is likely only the tip of the iceberg. If I were you, I would be looking to rename the current domain or migrate to a new domain with a proper name. Details on proper AD setup [can be found here](https://serverfault.com/questions/402580/what-is-active-directory-domain-services-and-how-does-it-work)

[KB300684](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300684) outlines the issues with single label names in more detail, including:

- Some server-based applications are incompatible with single-label domain names. Application support may not exist in the initial release of an application, or support may be dropped in a future release.
- The Active Directory Installation Wizard (Dcpromo.exe) in Windows Server 2008 warns against creating new domains that have single-label DNS names. Because there is no business or technical reason to create new domains that have single-label DNS names, the Active Directory Installation Wizard in Windows Server 2008 R2 explicitly blocks creating such domains.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve your domain FQDN with:

```
$env:USERDNSDOMAIN
```

if you domain FQDN really is `mydomainname`, append a dot, so it reads `mydomainname.`

Comment: my domain FQDN is `mydomainname` as I previously stated. I tried appending a dot as you said, but I keep getting the same error ...

Comment: `1.` Does ipconfig/all on this server show a primary DNS suffix? Do any of the network adapters show a connection-specific DNS suffix? `2.` If your FQDN is in fact `mydomainname` then you have a single label domain (SLD) and probably have bigger problems then just getting IPAM set up.

Comment: The ipconfig/all on this server shows a primary DNS suffix, `mydomainname`.The network adapter doesn't show a connection-specific DNS suffix... As it seems I have a SLD and from what I'm reading you might be right ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the commandlet expects a dotted-domain format that requires a dot followed by another name (like "foo.bar").

Try to either rename your domain or use a workaround, e.g.

- using a redirector in your DNS
- using the local HOSTS file

to get around this problem.