# Domain controller with new domain on my network

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I am migrating my organization from one domain to another. The old domain can be referred to as X, and the new domain is Y.

On domain X, I have created a VM that will act as a DC for domain Y.

Will creating the DC (and by extension, domain Y) on domain X cause any issues? Will these two domains conflict with each other if I don't initiate a trust relationship between the two?

Comment: When you say `on domain x` do you mean on the same network? If so, then there shouldn't be any problem. Just make sure you don't have conflicting ip addresses or NetBIOS names.

Comment: Correct, domain x and y will be on the same network.

Answer (score 1):

> Will creating the DC (and by extension, domain Y) on domain X cause any issues?

You cannot have a domain controller for one domain as a member of a different domain.  Domain controllers, in effect, **are** the domain for which they're on.

> Will these two domains conflict with each other if I don't initiate a trust relationship between the two?

The domains will effectively not be able to talk to each other, unless and until you establish a trust relationship.

Frankly, these are pretty basic questions that you have, and if I were you, I'd lean on  consultant, or a more senior colleague with relevant experience.  With your level of knowledge, you're begging for a disaster trying to set this up (and do a migration) yourself.

At a very minimum, you need to educate yourself on Active Directory.  [You could start with the excellent thread by @MDMarra that we have here](https://serverfault.com/q/402580/118258).